# Find and convert all timestamp columns to datatime in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and it has several column of timestmap in following formet

```
2021-01-21T12:25:21.000Z
```

converting to datetime

```
pd.Series(df.lastModifiedDate).astype('datetime64[ms]')
2021-01-21 12:25:21
```

Is there any way that I convert all the timestamp column at once without speciding each column manully?

only highlighted one are timestamp

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Comment: `df` contains object, float and int type only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could gather the column names by testing the format of each column in a row. That is, if the string of the column value matches a certain pattern, then you add that column to your list of columns

```
# if the pattern is more complex, replace with regex or longer pattern
dtcols = [c for c in df.columns if str(df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc(c)]).endswith('0Z')]

# use to_datetime rather than astype, you have more control over conversion
df.loc[:, dtcols] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, dtcols], errors='coerce')
```